# Display ErrorMessages when use @Html.Action

Tags: asp.net, view, partial, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a main view Index.cshtml and a partial view Contact.cshtml.Then use **@Html.Action("Contact", "Post")** in Index.cshtml.

This a position of Contact.cshtml in Index.cshtml
[image: This a position of Contact.cshtml in Index.cshtml]

This a contact.cshtml to register contact at index screen.
[image: This a contact.cshtml]

This a controller.
[image]

The problem here that I want if **ModelState.IsValid == false** then it returns   Index.cshtml with error messages and display ViewBag.Msg in Index.cshtml when **ModelState.IsValid == true** . But now it is not.

Hope the helping.

Comment: What kind of error messages you want to display when `ModelState.IsValid == false`? Is `ViewBag.Msg` contents not displayed after submitted data saved on DB?

Comment: I use @Html.ValidationMessageFor() to display error messages. And i can't transfer ViewBag.Msg to View.

Comment: Well, you have page redirect by `RedirectToAction` to `Index` page for both `ModelState` condition, since `ViewBag.Msg` only exists in `Contact` it doesn't shown in `Index`. You can use `TempData["Msg"]`/`Session["Msg"]` to pass stored string through redirect, or `return View(model)` when validation errors occur, where `model` is `LIEN_HE` class.